# Problem in compiling Latex code (LNCS Springer) sample

Tags: math-mode, errors, symbols, document-classes

I am using WinEdt editor and trying to compile the following code by using LNCS (Springer) sample tex file. Everything works fine except when I am using the command $\Box$ to add a symbol in the document. Kindly help me. Which package I am missing here? Thanks a lot for the help.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{ABCDEF \thanks{Supported by organization x.}}
\author{First Author\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-1111-2222-3333} \and
Second Author\inst{2,3}\orcidID{1111-2222-3333-4444} \and
Third Author\inst{3}\orcidID{2222--3333-4444-5555}}
\authorrunning{F. Author et al.}
\institute{Princeton University, Princeton NJ 08544, USA \and
Springer Heidelberg, Tiergartenstr. 17, 69121 Heidelberg, Germany
\email{lncs@springer.com}\\
\url{http://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs} \and
ABC Institute, Rupert-Karls-University Heidelberg, Heidelberg, Germany\\
\email{\{abc,lncs\}@uni-heidelberg.de}}

\maketitle              % typeset the header of the contribution
\begin{abstract}
The abstract should briefly summarize the contents of the paper in
15--250 words.

\keywords{First keyword  \and Second keyword \and Another keyword.}
\end{abstract}

\section{First Section}

\begin{theorem} 
Let $G_1\Box \ldots \Box G_n$ be .......
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much. It worked